# I cannot uninstall programs in xp.. jscript

Tags: regsvr32

I have XP and want to uninstall some progs so I can add Linux Mint to my disc.

I cannot uninstall so have used ..
  in Start Run ..  regsvr32 jscript.dll  but get this message..

Any help please ?

Thanks

oz

---

That is where I am trying to uninstall and get this message..

The softeware cannot be installed because Jscript is not properly registered. Please repair Jscript then restart the installer.

It looks like it is mostly Adobe Products.

It was then  suggested I can fix that Jscript problem with regsvr32 jscript.dll but it dos not work.

oz

Answer (score 0):

regsvr32 has nothing to do with uninstallation.

Use the control panel applet:
Start Menu -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Add / Remove Programs